# GNOME on Ubuntu?

Tags: 14.04

I'm currently running Ubuntu 14.04 running GNOME. I Just installed gnome, logged out and back in, the login bar appeared as gnome, so did the profiles, but the sidebar is still unity?

EDIT: When I restart it switches back to Unity, I want gnome (sudo apt-get install gnome).

Comment: http://ubuntugnome.org/ claims to provide complete installation of Ubuntu using gnome.